# Looking for Windows macro utility that creates toolbars that can be docked in other Windows apps

Tags: macros, toolbar, utility, dock

About 10 years ago there was a macro utility that created toolbars that could be docked within other Windows applications. I can't remember the name of this product and have been unable to find it via Google.

Are there any Windows macro utilities that have this capability? I've seen some utilities like Quick Macros (QM) that allow one to create floating toolbars, but so far no utilities which support the docking capability I'm looking for.

Does anyone remember the name of the original product I'm referring to and/or have recommendations on Windows macro utilities.

Thanks,
Malcolm